# Burninate [type-safety]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [type-safety](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-safety) tag is used to mean all sorts of different things:

- In all languages, it often refers to some sort of [enum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enum).
- In C++, it often means [template](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template) (Edit: there is a proposal to [merge into generics](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5742/merge-request-template-generics)).
- In C# and Java), it often means [generics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generics). (most other languages that support the concept use word too).
- I'm not sure exactly what it means in Haskell, F#, and Scala.

There are only 41 questions so it should be an easy burnination. Most of the questions already have the appropriate other tag so nothing is lost if we just delete it.

Comment: Type-safety and enum/template/generics are extraordinarily different concepts...

Comment: @nhgrif Tell that to the people who tagged the questions then.

Comment: Downvoting not necessarily because I disagree, but because this question is nearly incoherent and I can't figure out whether or not I agree.

Comment: @RubberDuck This question exists because I was recently asked to add it to a python program (instead of a more specific tag), but most people would immediately say "type-safety doesn't even mean anything in Python!". And the 41 questions prove that type-safety doesn't mean any single thing in general; it means different things for each question.

Comment: So, you want to burn the tag because it's not appropriate for Python? I'm really trying to understand here, but you've gotta do more to make us understand where you're coming from here.

Comment: @RubberDuck because if you look at the questions, it doesn't mean anything consistent at all. It's like using [tag:set] for all 85 definitions of the word. See [when to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

Answer (score 7):

[type-safety](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-safety) has a number of questions where the tag seems relevant:

- checking the types of values before feeding them in to a printf-style format: [Compile-time printf-style format checking](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85031/compile-time-printf-style-format-checking) (this is a follow-on to another question too).
- checking types before casting: [Proper use of type_info in relation to mapping components to a type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84176/proper-use-of-type-info-in-relation-to-mapping-components-to-a-type)
- Managing values in a set: [Designing a Variable Set](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81829/designing-a-variable-set)

These counter examples indicate times when the tag is used usefully.

Despite other situations where it may be used wrong, it is also clear that it can be used well, and as a consequence, burnination would be inappropriate.

Comment: this also implies that mistaggings may have to be cleaned up..

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think the tag should be burned, this question prompted me to do a clean up of the tag, as it seemed to be thought necessary, regardless that it's a good tag. I just went through the bottom half of the questions tagged with [type-safety](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-safety) and did not remove it from a single question. It seems to be used appropriately on all the questions I looked at.

I encourage the community to take a second look and see if there are any questions where the tag should be removed.