# Synonym request: [template] -> [generics]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

As far as I can tell, [template](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template) is basically just C++'s version of [generics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generics).

If this is correct and there is no other appropriate use of the [template](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template) tag (the tag says it's not supposed to be used for "template-meta-programming"), then I recommend we synonimize [template](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template) into [generics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generics).

<sub>As a note, this tag almost certainly has some improper uses for things like "template-meta-programming" which the wiki cautions against, and probably some other things, so it'd need some clean-up.</sub>

Comment: I agree, especially since Rust calls them generics but they act more like C++ templates than Java generics.

Comment: I don't know enough about C++ to know for sure that a C++ template is equivalent enough to a Swift/Java/C# generic.

Comment: Language-wise, [there is a big difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347/what-are-the-differences-between-generic-types-in-c-and-java) between C++ templates and generics in a language like Java, for instance, however, since both tags seem to represent the same *concept*, creating the synonym might be adequate.

Comment: @glampert Would you mind posting, as an answer, an elaboration on the differences between C++ templates and say Java generics?

Comment: humm, let me think about for a while, I'm not fully decided on either side yet `:P`

Comment: IMO if you exclude [tag:template-meta-programming] (which should not be hyphenated btw) all that's left is implementations differences. I mean, the implementations differences are often significant, but ...

Comment: @glampert Based on that link, I think synonimization is right.  For example, Swift generics don't require you to specify a class or protocol (but you can).

Comment: Yep, like I said, it is the same overall concept, so from that standpoint, they could be merged, however, if you look into the questions tagged with `template`, the majority seems to be c++, while `generics` is a mix of mainly Java and C#. Should those be mixed together? I don't know...

Comment: As far as I can tell, "generics" is basically just Java's version of C++'s "template".

Answer (score 10):

### No.

Templates and Generics, though similar enough in some ways, are different enough in other ways to the point where a person expert in one will have little or no valuable insight on the other. A person who follows [templates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templates) will not likely follow [generics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generics) (and vice versa). This makes it different from other language-agnostic tags like [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list), etc...

Tags have two purposes - a broad classification of questions, but also as landmarks that users use to find questions to answer. Merging these tags will make life "worse" for people who follow them, not better, and will add little, or no value for people asking questions either.

So, no, do not mix these two.

Comment: So which tag should we use for Rust "generics", which act like C++ templates?

Comment: @o11c If the documentation calls them generics, use generics. If it calls them templates, use templates. Don't mix them.

Comment: @Mast Okay, so the tag `generics` gets used for (quoting) "similar enough in some ways, are different enough in other ways to the point where a person expert in one will have little or no valuable insight on the other". Gotcha.

Comment: Keep in mind that [tag:template] should *not* be used for [tag:template-meta-programming], which I think covers all the things that [tag:generics] can't do.

Answer (score 9):

From a technical standpoint, [if we look into](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36347/1198654) the way C++ templates are implemented vs how Java generics are implemented, there is a big difference. C# generics [are implemented in a way more similar to C++ templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31929/1198654), but there are a few differences as well. Certainly there's more, but these are the languages I know about.

From a semantic standpoint, my understanding is that both *templates* and *generics* represent the same concept of [*type generic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming). From this perspective, then yes, the words are synonyms.

Now from a cultural standpoint, I don't recall ever hearing a C++ programmer use the term *generics* to talk about *templates*, so I'm not sure if mixing both terminologies is a good idea due to the historial meaning of the word *template* in the C++ community.

So in the end, all that beating around the bush is my way of saying that I'm not sure `:P`. It seems to me that I can go both ways just as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, you'll never hear an iOS developer talking about [hash-maps], but [dictionary] has been made a synonym of [hash-map].  Thanks for your input.